# Docker compose command fails as root user

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose

I'm having a hard time figuring out what's wrong.

when I run `docker-compose -f ./docker-compose.yml build parallel` I get this output, saying that docker isn't running (which isn't true, see below)

```bash
joel@ogofe:/home/dev/udagram$ docker-compose -f ./docker-compose.yml build parallel
/home/joel/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/__init__.py:109: RequestsDependencyWarning: urllib3 (1.26.9) or chardet (5.0.0)/charset_normalizer (2.0.6) doesn't match a supported version!
  warnings.warn(
ERROR: Couldn't connect to Docker daemon at http://172.17.0.0:2375 - is it running?

If it's at a non-standard location, specify the URL with the DOCKER_HOST environment variable.
```

I've checked the status of the docker service, and it's up and running. I even tried restarting it to no avail.
Also worth knowing: I've scoured Stack Overflow for a fix, but haven't found one yet. I did get a nudge in the right direction (I hope) suggesting that it's a permission issue (ie docker-compose can't see the running service because it was started by the root user)

```bash
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2022-09-01 06:36:18 WAT; 2h 45min ago
TriggeredBy: ● docker.socket
       Docs: https://docs.docker.com
   Main PID: 15087 (dockerd)
      Tasks: 159
     Memory: 34.2M
        CPU: 5.999s
     CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service
             └─15087 /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock

Sep 01 06:35:46 ogofe dockerd[15087]: time="2022-09-01T06:35:46.555705337+01:00" level=info msg="ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{unix:///run/containerd/cont>
Sep 01 06:35:46 ogofe dockerd[15087]: time="2022-09-01T06:35:46.555733870+01:00" level=info msg="ClientConn switching balancer to \"pick_first\"" module=grpc
Sep 01 06:35:49 ogofe dockerd[15087]: time="2022-09-01T06:35:49.830692206+01:00" level=info msg="[graphdriver] using prior storage driver: overlay2"
Sep 01 06:36:07 ogofe dockerd[15087]: time="2022-09-01T06:36:07.519863155+01:00" level=info msg="Loading containers: start."
Sep 01 06:36:15 ogofe dockerd[15087]: time="2022-09-01T06:36:15.201916110+01:00" level=info msg="Default bridge (docker0) is assigned with an IP address 172.17.0.0/16. >
Sep 01 06:36:15 ogofe dockerd[15087]: time="2022-09-01T06:36:15.796809326+01:00" level=info msg="Loading containers: done."
Sep 01 06:36:17 ogofe dockerd[15087]: time="2022-09-01T06:36:17.811988794+01:00" level=info msg="Docker daemon" commit=363e9a8 graphdriver(s)=overlay2 version=20.10.5
Sep 01 06:36:18 ogofe dockerd[15087]: time="2022-09-01T06:36:18.465597339+01:00" level=info msg="Daemon has completed initialization"
Sep 01 06:36:18 ogofe systemd[1]: Started Docker Application Container Engine.
Sep 01 06:36:18 ogofe dockerd[15087]: time="2022-09-01T06:36:18.893028725+01:00" level=info msg="API listen on /run/docker.sock"
```

However, running `sudo docker-compose ...` doesn't seem to work either, and I'm greeted with a new error. I am at a loss here, and I'm running out of time to submit this project.

```bash
joel@ogofe:/home/dev/udagram$ sudo docker-compose -f ./docker-compose.yml build parallel
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/docker-compose", line 5, in <module>
    from compose.cli.main import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'compose'
```

I know my writing could use a lot of work, but I hope this is at least clear enough for someone to understand my challenge.

Thank You for the help. Cheers!

PS: I'm running on a Kali Linux distro, and I have docker-desktop installed.

Comment: That's not a normal location for the Docker socket.  On Linux I'd normally expect it to be the file `/var/run/docker.sock`; you should pretty much never be able to access Docker on port 2375 for security reasons.  Do you have the environment variable `$DOCKER_HOST` set, and if so, does unsetting it help?

Comment: @DavidMaze Yes, I have tried that, it still shows the same error, only instead of `172.17.0.0` it shows `docker://localhost`. I even copied the `docker-compose` command to `/usr/local/bin/` but it still didn't work. Nonetheless, let me give it another shot and if it works, I'll notify you. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it working.

1. First I had to reinstall `docker-compose` by running `curl -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/docker/compose-cli/main/scripts/install/install_linux.sh | sh`
2. I noticed that running `sudo docker-compose` was the wrong format of the command, instead I used `sudo docker compose -f ./docker-compose-build.yml build --parallel` and it worked fine.

Thanks @DavidMaze for your help.